# Change dynamic components on JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have an entity named Interview. In this entity I have different types of question - (1-5, Y/N, free answer). I want to be able to answer this questions. The problem is that the interface components of XHTML will change according to type of question. For example, if it's a Y/N question, I want to be able to introduce a combo box. For a free answer I want to make a textarea.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use the `rendered` attribute for the combo box and the text area, and change its value dynamically depending on the question type. But nobody here will write the code for you, this is a site where you are expected to post a concrete problem you have with your code.